# Swift Expandable tableView cell buttons are not appearing upon scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

When scrolling off the screen with my custom cell in an expanded state the buttons are being hidden which should not be the case. Beneath the labels, 2 buttons are not appearing when scrolling up again. I'm guessing something needs to happen after the cell has been dequeued. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

I have a custom cell where initially the height for a row is 80, upon clicking on the cell it expands to 120. By default I have the buttons hidden like so:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            followButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var blockButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            blockButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

I have an `var expandedIndexSet : IndexSet = []` which tracks which cell has been expanded.
The method below updates indexSet accordingly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! StackOverflowTableViewCell

        if(expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row)){
            expandedIndexSet.remove(indexPath.row)
        } else {
            expandedIndexSet.insert(indexPath.row)
        }

        cell.blockButton.isHidden = !cell.blockButton.isHidden
        cell.followButton.isHidden = !cell.followButton.isHidden

        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

The height gets adjusted like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row) {
            return 140
        }
        else {
            return 80
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not quite sure about your use-case, but `didSet { followButton.isHidden = true }` seems to be unusual to me. What exactly you want to do with this snippet? Are you setting these buttons from outside? Try to comment them out and use `awakeFromNib()` instead to initially hide these buttons. Also add a break point in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` to check whether it's getting called to refresh cell height once you select a cell.

Comment: The use case is when a user taps a cell on the tableView the cell should expand height so it can display 2 buttons (follow/block). When the user taps the cell again the the buttons should be hidden and the cell goes back to it's default size, similar to a drop down menu effect. I've tried removing the didSet property observers and moved them into the awakeFromNib but still no luck.

Comment: did you try adding a breakpoint in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` to check if this function is getting called during the animation?

Comment: Yes i've added a breakpoint to verify the height is being adjusted as expected. The issue is when a selected cell that is in an expanded state is scrolled past and not visible on the screen the buttons are hidden and is affecting other cells.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet might be helpful, please try.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = ....

         cell.followButton.isHidden = !expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row)
         cell.blockButton.isHidden = cell.followButton.isHidden

         return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        // Update View Model
        if(expandedIndexSet.contains(indexPath.row)){
            expandedIndexSet.remove(indexPath.row)
        } else {
            expandedIndexSet.insert(indexPath.row)
        }

        // Table View Animation
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: This worked however it has disabled an imageView being set when the user closes the cell.
```  
@IBAction func followButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if isFollowingUserImage.isHidden {
            isFollowingUserImage.isHidden = false
            followButton.setTitle("Unfollow", for: .normal)
        } else {
            isFollowingUserImage.isHidden = true
            followButton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: No sure what you exactly mean by `it has disabled an imageView being set when the user closes the cell`, is it the image view you are trying to hide/unhide when user taps on the `follow` button? If you are trying to change the height of the cell on button tap, 1. update the data model which might have the info whether to show the image view 2. Calculate the new height in `func tableView(_ tableView: heightForRowAt indexPath:) -> CGFloat` 3. You need to reload the cell again to update it's height.
4. manage your constraints within your cell with the data from your model to do the changes.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what i'm trying to do when the follow button is clicked it the imageView should appear which it does however when the user taps the cell again the imageView disappears which is incorrect. When you tap the cell and it expands it shows the imageView.